# Write a program that reads an input file and identifies all duplicated words

Tags: c

The program should print first the list of duplicated words followed by the list of unique words.

ive been trying to code this but it still wont work it only prints a few unique words pls help me
this is what ive done so far btw im using codeblocks

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{

 FILE* inp;
 char word[BUFSIZ],input[BUFSIZ][BUFSIZ],dup[BUFSIZ][BUFSIZ],unique[BUFSIZ][BUFSIZ];
int c=0,k=0,NumWord=0,n=0,found=0,m=1,g=0,j=0,h=0,b=1,d=1,a=0,size,detect=1,p=0;
char arr[BUFSIZ][BUFSIZ];

inp=fopen("u.txt","r")  ;

if(inp==NULL){perror("Error in opening a file") ;return ;}
while(fscanf(inp,"%s",word)!=EOF)
{
    strcpy(input[c++],word)  ;
    ++NumWord;

}

size = NumWord - 1  ;

for( a=0 ; a < size ;a++)
{
    //detect=1;
    for( ; b < NumWord ; b++)
    {
            if(strcmp(input[a],input[b])==0 && detect==1)
            {
                strcpy(dup[a],input[a]) ;
                ++detect;
                ++h;
                ++found;
            }
    }

        b = ++d;
        if(!found)
        {
            strcpy(unique[n++],input[a]) ;
        }
    detect=1;
}

   for( g = 0; g <h ; g++){
       printf("%s ",dup[g]);

      }
   fclose(inp);

  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include 1) a short sample file, 2) expected result and 3) actual result.

Comment: Also please indent your code properly and please make it a habit to give your variables meaningful names, rather than one-letter ones.

Comment: Where did you define `BUFSIZ` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need different indexes for `dup` and `unique` buffers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* inp;
    char word[BUFSIZ],input[BUFSIZ][BUFSIZ],dup[BUFSIZ][BUFSIZ],unique[BUFSIZ][BUFSIZ];
    int c=0,k=0,NumWord=0,n=0,found=0,m=1,g=0,j=0,h=0,b=1,d=1,a=0,size,detect=1,p=0;
    char arr[BUFSIZ][BUFSIZ];

    int dup_idx =0;
    int unique_idx =0;

    inp=fopen("u.txt","r")  ;

    if(inp==NULL)
    {
        perror("Error in opening a file") ;return ;
    }

    while(fscanf(inp,"%s",word)!=EOF)
    {
        strcpy(input[c++],word)  ;
        ++NumWord;

    }

    size = NumWord - 1  ;

    for( a=0 ; a < size ;a++)
    {
        //detect=1;
        for(b = 0; b < NumWord ; b++)
        {
                if(strcmp(input[a],input[b])==0 && detect==1)
                {
                    strcpy(dup[dup_idx++],input[a]) ;
                    ++detect;
                    ++found;
                }
        }

        b = ++d;
        if(!found)
        {
            strcpy(unique[unique_idx++],input[a]) ;
        }

        detect=1;
    }

    printf("Dup: ");
    for( g = 0; g < dup_idx ; g++){
        printf("%s ",dup[g]);
    }

    printf("\nUnique: ");
    for( g = 0; g < unique_idx ; g++){
        printf("%s ",dup[g]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    fclose(inp);

  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to initialize your string buffers `dup` and `unique`. This is probably not the cause of your problems but if you don't, your program has undefined behaviour when you print `dup`.

```
memset(dup, 0, sizeof dup);
memset(dup, 0, sizeof unique);
```

Second, I don't understand the way you assign `b`. A simplistic start would be to remove the line `b = ++d;` and assign `b` in the `for` loop:

```
for(b = a + 1; b < NumWord ; b++)
```

It is sufficient to look in the rest of the array, because if a word has a duplicate prior to itself it will have been detected when that prior word was processed.